# What the product of this reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds, rearrangements

The reaction is as follows, with (i) being my answer, and (ii) being the correct answer in the book.

[image]

My question is why is the product (ii) formed here and elimination not favoured here? I think that the first structure is more stable(has extended conjugation) whereas the latter is relatively unstable. I do understand that the carbocation formed during the formation of (ii) is highly stable (cyclopropyl carbocation and has extended conjugation with phenyl), but is this the reason why (ii) is the major product?

Comment: The first structure has a less strained ring???!! Who told you that?

Comment: Likely the rearrangement to the more stable cation is the driving force.  In addition to the stability of the rearranged ion, the rearrangement itself is likely to be kinetically facile as it involves a simple electron-pair move and forms the new bond between atoms that are already relatively close together (1,3 in a four-member ring).

Comment: @Waylander I get it now, 1st is more strained because of 2 sp2 carbons in a ring. But isn't it more stable because of extended conjugation. Will edit the question now

Comment: @OscarLanzi But if a lot of heat is provided can it form (i)? Is (i) more stable than (ii) at all?

Comment: @TheQuestioner  The ring strain is a much larger factor than the extended conjugation

Comment: I would guess heating would only promote the rearrangement.

Comment: Beacause of formation of **CPM** (**Cyclopropylmethyl carbocation**) which is extremely stable due to the presence of **dancing resonance** which is found in this as an **exception**..

Comment: The intermediate is a cyclopropylmethyl cation. It would be reasonable to suggest that you get a mixture of product here.

Comment: Wouldn't the ring contracted intermediate be a benzylic substituted cation, which can stabilise to an aromatic tropylium cation?